# Switching items JS classes

Tags: javascript

I added the "setHeight" function to make the smooth opening/closing of items with dynamic content work.
The essence of the function, if the item with class "active" - then the height of the content is automatic from the height of the parent block (if you look at the function in the JS code, it will be clearer how it works).
If we click on the active item and it becomes inactive - everything works correctly.
The content height becomes 0 and the content is hidden.
Now the problem is that if we click not on active item but on another one and "active" class is removed from active item and another item is added - then content height is not removed from previous active item to "0".

How can I

```js
const accordItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

accordItems.forEach(item => {
    const accordText = item.querySelector('.accordion__text');
    const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');
    
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const activeItem = item.classList.contains('active');

        accordItems.forEach(item => {
          item.classList.remove('active');
          setHeight()
        });
        
        if (!activeItem) {
            content.style.height = 0;
        }

        if (!activeItem) {
            item.classList.add('active');
            setHeight()
        }

      });

      function setHeight() {
        if (content.offsetHeight) {
        content.style.height = 0;
        } else {
        content.style.height = accordText.offsetHeight + 'px';
        };
        };
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  background: #f2f2f2; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

h5 {
  margin: 0; }

p {
  margin: 0; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 140rem; }

.section-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 134rem;
  margin: auto; }

.accordion-image {
  width: 630px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url("https://eternel.maitreart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/creat-home-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }

.accordion {
  width: 63rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 8rem; }
  .accordion__item {
    border-top: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s;
    padding-bottom: 1rem; }
    .accordion__item.active {
      height: auto; }
    .accordion__item:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a6a4; }
  .accordion__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    cursor: pointer; }
  .accordion__title {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .accordion__icon {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    transition: transform .5s ease; }
    .accordion__icon span:first-child {
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(1px);
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor; }
    .accordion__icon span {
      display: block;
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor;
      cursor: pointer; }
  .accordion__content {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.62;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s; }

.accordion__item.active > .accordion__header .accordion__icon {
  transform: rotate(45deg); }

.accordion__item.active > .accordion__content {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  height: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <section class="section-accordion">
            <div class="accordion-image"></div>
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__item active">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Visual direction</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Event production</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Brand creation</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Design concept</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your Javsacript a bit to achieve it, your problem is your `content` always refers to the current item which is not the previous active item. We need pass `item` param to that function to refer to a correct item.

The key changes are under `setHeight` function

```
function setHeight(item, isActive) {
   const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');
   if (!isActive) {
      content.style.height = 0;
   } else {
       content.style.height = accordText.offsetHeight + 'px';
   };
};
```

```js
const accordItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

accordItems.forEach(item => {
    const accordText = item.querySelector('.accordion__text');
    
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const activeItem = item.classList.contains('active');

        accordItems.forEach(item => {
          item.classList.remove('active');
          setHeight(item, false)
        });

        if (!activeItem) {
            item.classList.add('active');
            setHeight(item, true)
        }

      });

      function setHeight(item, isActive) {
        const content = item.querySelector('.accordion__content');
        if (!isActive) {
        content.style.height = 0;
        } else {
        content.style.height = accordText.offsetHeight + 'px';
        };
        };
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  background: #f2f2f2; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

h5 {
  margin: 0; }

p {
  margin: 0; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 140rem; }

.section-accordion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 134rem;
  margin: auto; }

.accordion-image {
  width: 630px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url("https://eternel.maitreart.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/creat-home-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }

.accordion {
  width: 63rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 8rem; }
  .accordion__item {
    border-top: 1px solid #a8a6a4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s;
    padding-bottom: 1rem; }
    .accordion__item.active {
      height: auto; }
    .accordion__item:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a6a4; }
  .accordion__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    cursor: pointer; }
  .accordion__title {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .accordion__icon {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    transition: transform .5s ease; }
    .accordion__icon span:first-child {
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(1px);
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor; }
    .accordion__icon span {
      display: block;
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: .1rem;
      background: currentColor;
      cursor: pointer; }
  .accordion__content {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.62;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .5s; }

.accordion__item.active > .accordion__header .accordion__icon {
  transform: rotate(45deg); }

.accordion__item.active > .accordion__content {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  height: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <section class="section-accordion">
            <div class="accordion-image"></div>
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__item active">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Visual direction</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Event production</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Brand creation</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__header">
                            <h5 class="accordion__title">Design concept</h5>
                            <div class="accordion__icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__content">
                            <p class="accordion__text">Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. 
                            Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. 
                            Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```